# Excel: How to replace only trailing strings?

Tags: excel

I need to replace only trailing strings in Excel.. Currently I have this data:

```
Sony Co
Coca Cola
Coke
Sony Company
```

I would like to remove only the " Co" from the Sony line

So output is like this:

```
Sony
Coca Cola
Coke
Sony Company
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Find and Replace > Find What : = Sony Co > Replace With : =Sony > Click Options > Check Match entire cell contents > Replace All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("Co", TRIM(A1), LEN(TRIM(A1)) - 2)), A1, LEFT(A1,LEN(TRIM(A1)) - 2))
```

Comment: Incase others need, use SEARCH instead of FIND for case insensitive:
``=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Co", TRIM(A1), LEN(TRIM(A1)) - 2)), A1, LEFT(A1,LEN(TRIM(A1)) - 2))``